# Comparación de descripciones similare

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo en python que busca encontrar la mejor coincidencia entre los valores (Descripción) de la hoja "BoQ" dispuestos en la columna C y los valores (Descripción) de la hoja "DB" dispuestos en la columna C y devolver el resultado de la comparación en la hoja "BoQ" en las columnas F, I y J correspondientes a las columnas E, A y B de la hoja "DB". No Me funciona bien respecto a la comparación de similitudes que resulta. Lo que quiero tener es mayor coincidencia para que mejore el resultado final y sea mas confiable

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
import xlwings as xw
from collections import Counter
import re
import unicodedata
import math

# Función para calcular la similitud entre dos cadenas de texto

def similaridad(str1, str2):
    # Limpiar las cadenas de texto
    str1_limpio = limpiar_texto(str1)
    str2_limpio = limpiar_texto(str2)

    # Obtener los tokens de las cadenas de texto
    tokens_str1 = str1_limpio.split()
    tokens_str2 = str2_limpio.split()

    # Obtener el vector de frecuencia de cada token en las cadenas de texto
    vector_str1 = Counter(tokens_str1)
    vector_str2 = Counter(tokens_str2)

    # Obtener la intersección de los tokens en ambas cadenas de texto
    intersection = set(vector_str1.keys()) & set(vector_str2.keys())

    # Calcular el numerador del coseno de similitud
    numerador = sum([vector_str1[x] * vector_str2[x] for x in intersection])

    # Calcular el denominador del coseno de similitud
    magnitud_str1 = math.sqrt(sum([vector_str1[x] ** 2 for x in vector_str1.keys()]))
    magnitud_str2 = math.sqrt(sum([vector_str2[x] ** 2 for x in vector_str2.keys()]))
    denominador = magnitud_str1 * magnitud_str2

    # Calcular el coseno de similitud
    coseno_similitud = numerador / denominador if denominador != 0 else 0

    return coseno_similitud

# Función para remover caracteres especiales y acentos
def limpiar_texto(texto):
    texto_limpio = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', texto).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
    texto_limpio = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', texto_limpio)
    return texto_limpio

# Definir las hojas de Excel a utilizar y obtener la última fila de datos en cada hoja
wb = xw.Book('Referencia.xlsm')
db_sheet = wb.sheets['DB']
boq_sheet = wb.sheets['BoQ']

db_sheet.activate()
last_db_row = db_sheet.range('C' + str(db_sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

boq_sheet.activate()
last_boq_row = boq_sheet.range('C' + str(boq_sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

# Crear un array de valores de la hoja DB
db_array = db_sheet.range('C3:C' + str(last_db_row)).value

# Recorrer cada celda en la columna C de la hoja BoQ
for i in range(3, last_boq_row + 1):
    # Crear un array de valores de la celda actual de la hoja BoQ
    boq_array = limpiar_texto(boq_sheet.range('C' + str(i)).value).split()
    # Inicializar variables para la comparación
    max_similitud = 0
    match_row = 0

    # Comparar los valores del array de la celda actual con los valores de la hoja DB
    for j in range(3, last_db_row - 1):
        if j >= len(db_array):
            break
        db_desc_array = limpiar_texto(db_array[j][0]).split()
        total_similitud = 0
        for boq_word in boq_array:
            max_word_similitud = 0
            for db_word in db_desc_array:
                similitud = similaridad(db_word, boq_word)
                if similitud > max_word_similitud:
                    max_word_similitud = similitud
            total_similitud += max_word_similitud
        similitud_promedio = total_similitud / len(boq_array)
        if similitud_promedio > max_similitud:
            max_similitud = similitud_promedio
            match_row = j

    # Escribir el resultado de la comparación en la columna F, I y J de la hoja BoQ
    boq_sheet.range('F' + str(i)).value = db_sheet.range('E' + str(match_row)).value
    boq_sheet.range('I' + str(i)).value = db_sheet.range('A' + str(match_row)).value
    boq_sheet.range('J' + str(i)).value = db_sheet.range('B' + str(match_row)).value
```

Comparto el archivo de referencia que estoy utilizando

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChNs5rTdCIv65oRde6zE_p9wKzwUwiYC/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Creo que no te será posible establecer una comparación simple con descripciones tan similares y extensas, con diferencias mínimas de unos dígitos o unos pocos caracteres. El problema requiere de _ciencia de datos_, en concreto de la aplicación de técnicas de *machine learning* para hacer clasificaciones que permitan hacer comparaciones. Demasiado complejo, aunque, por suerte, no es difícil encontrar documentación y cursos sobre ello.

Comment: @ChemaCortes hay alguna firma de hacerlo con python que me acerque a un resultado mejor?

Comment: Se me ocurre alguna forma de simplificar las descripciones para que sean más cortas y específicas, limpiando el contenido dentro de todos los paréntesis o sólo tomando un rango inicial de caracteres andes de un signo de puntuación (. ,) o agrupando palabras que se repitan en la descripciones antes de analizar y comparar los arreglos Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan prestar aunque sea pequeña

Comment: Te recomendaría la misma técnica que el *machine learning*: crea un diccionario de palabras claves que puedan discriminar una descripción de otra (construcción, electricidad, acero, galvanizados, etc, etc.) y puntúalas según sea su relación, mayor o menor, con cada uno de los elementos del catálogo. Con este modelo, busca esas palabras clave en la entrada y localiza el elemento del catálogo que mejor puntúe, ajustando el modelo según lo vayas viendo. Es tedioso hacerlo a mano, mejor usar algo como [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) que lo automatize, pero requiere conocimientos.